# Can Extension scripts be triggered BEFORE page scripts?

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I am forced to use a web application written (over a decade ago I'm guessing) for IE6 and only works with IE (newer versions in quirks mode). I have been able to repair some of the more egregious javascript with a Safari extension that injects scripts to detach event handlers and replace them with DOM compliant versions.

I am now turning my attention to annoyances rather than the downright broken. The heavy handed use of alerts to inform the user of progress is painful. I thought it would be a fairly nice addition to my extension to override the window.alert function with some css popovers, but the challenge I am having is with pages that are sent back after an http post, where the first thing they do is display a success (or failure) alert.

According to [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH6-SW5) "a Start Script executes when the document has been created but before the webpage has been parsed". I would have thought that if the page hadn't been parsed, the scripts in the page's body's script tags wouldn't run, but this is not the behaviour I am seeing. Instead, it appears that any scripts in the page returned from the post response execute before my start script even loads.

To test this I have a very simple start script that logs to the console location.href and tries to replace window.alert with console.log.

The injected start script:

```
console.log(window.location.href + "loaded killAlert.js") ;
window.alert=function(str) { console.log(str) ; }
```

The test web page:

```
<html><head></head>
 <body>
  <script>alert("this is an alert message") ;</script>
  nothing to see here... move along.
 </body>
</html>
```

What happens is that when loading a test page with a script embedded, the alert executes before anything is written to console.log.

My questions—

- When do start scripts *actually* get called?
- Is there any way I can get them to execute *before* any scripts on the page?

While this seems like it should be fairly straight forward, but so far I haven't been able to find a way around the problem through reading documentation, search or experimenting. I'm hoping someone else has solved something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <head>
    <script>
    (function() {
        console.log(window.location.href + "loaded killAlert.js") ;
        window.alert=function(str) { console.log(str) ; }
    })();
    </script>
 </head>
```

Try calling it anonymously, it will execute the script immediately after the creation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Holybreath. I had already tried that - but came to the conclusion there was no advantage. The script is being called, but after the in page scripts have executed (which as I point out in the OP seems contrary to Apple's documentation).